# prevent router-link when clicked on the button inside it: VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, router

I've been struggling on preventing the router link when clicked on the button inside it, e.g:

```
<router-link to="/a">
  <div>...</div>
  <button @click.prevent="somemethod()"></button>
</router-link>
```

When i click on the the child button, i don't want router-link to go on the route

Comment: The normal case would be calling the method and not the router. Perhaps you can share a fiddle in order to present a more detailed scenario of your issue

Comment: I think you want `@click.stop="somemethod"`. `.prevent` only prevents the default event action

Comment: @ZuhaibKhan Your example seems to behave as expected in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-click-issue-in-router-link-o2i1e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark).

Comment: Thanks. @click.stop="somemethod" works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a button. I don't see any button text. Add a button text.Then press submit.

`<button @click.prevent="somemethod()">SUBMIT</button>`